# Make a redirect without rendering the redirect page

Tags: python, redirect, flask

After a user submitted some data to make a new object I want the backend to redirect him to the object detail, as usual:

I'm doing something like:

```
if obj.is_valid():
    obj.save()
    flash('%s created' % obj, )
    return redirect(url_for('provider', provider_id=obj.id))
```

But doing te request via curl (I'm building an API, testing it with curl)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/provider/11">/provider/11</a>.  If not click the link.
user@box
```

Which is unfortunate because I only want the response of `/provider/:id` not the intermediate step.

What's the correct way to address this issue?

Comment: You don't want to use a redirect at all if you don't want the server sending a redirect page. Call the method which renders the `/provider/11` page directly instead. Be aware that if you do that, the browser URL will show whatever address they originally hit (not `/provider/11`), and refreshing the page will hit it again.

Comment: No, I want a redirect, not to call the mothod directly... Django's redirect does the thing properly...

Comment: @tutaca "properly" means different things to different people. Do you mean an HTTP 302 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 )? That's what Flask should already be setting when you use the code above. You didn't give us the HTTP headers which accompanied the response page...

Comment: Man... The thing is doing a vanilla redirect (just read the code), which is a 302 by flask's default (the docs say so)... Properly means without generating html when I didn't ask for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-L` to instruct curl that it should follow HTTP redirects, and only show the final response:

```sh
$ curl -s http://www.exyr.org|grep '<title>' 
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
$ curl -s -L http://www.exyr.org|grep '<title>'
  <title>Exyr.org</title>
```

In `man curl`:

```
   -L, --location
          (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the server reports that the requested page has
          moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
          and  a  3XX  response code), this option will make curl redo the
          request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or
          -I, --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown. When
          authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials  to  the
          initial  host.  If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it
          won't be able to intercept the user+password. See  also  --loca‐
          tion-trusted  on how to change this. You can limit the amount of
          redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

          When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain  GET
          (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with
          a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
          code  was  any  other  3xx code, curl will re-send the following
          request using the same unmodified method.
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Flask is doing the correct thing here as defined by [RFC 2616 section 10.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2)

> The new permanent URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
> response. Unless the request method was HEAD, *the entity of the
> response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to
> the new URI(s).*

[emphasis mine]

Citing [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119), this paragraph could be paraphrased as:

> HTTP servers must include a short hypertext note with 30X redirects *unless they have a very good reason to avoid doing so*

No one using a browser or any common HTTP library will ever see that page - the client will follow the redirect provided in the `Location` header as specified in the relevant section of RFC 2616.

Pendantic lecturing aside, if you are building a JSON API and you want to serve nothing except the status code and the necessary headers you can do that by registering your own error handler for the appropriate methods by using the [`Flask.errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) decorator or [`Flask.register_error_handler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler):

```
@app.errorhandler(302)
def minimal_redirect():
    return u"", 302
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar query, as flask redirected to the **Redirect Page** before redirecting to the destination itself.

Just removing the `code` actually solved the problem. You can also specify custom route/handler for each `code`.

```
redirect(url_for('home'), code=302)
```

to,

```
redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Or as @Sean Vieira pointed out, use this decorator to handle redirect

```
@app.errorhandler(302)
def custom_redirect():
    # Return template
```

Answer (score 0):

You cloud simple remove the HTTP body of the `redirect` response.

```
res = redirect(url_for('provider', provider_id=obj.id))
res.data = ""
return res
```

Comment: No, this will only return a blank response... I want the final url response ('/provider/11', in this case.)